# Cambiar texto botón sin perder icono

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un botón drop down. El botón contiene un icono y cuando selecciono alguna opción de la lista el texto del botón cambia por el nombre correspondiente. Mi problema surge cuando cambia el nombre del botón, el icono no se muestra. ¿Cómo puedo mantener el icono del botón después de cambiar el nombre?
Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
        <div class="dropdown-opc"> 
           <a href="#" class="btnopc">item&nbsp;<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
           <div class="opc-list">
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Usa un elemento `<span>` para encerrar el texto del botón (sin el icono) y cambia sólo el contenido de dicho `<span>`. Por ejemplo: `<a href="#" ><span>title</span><i class="..."></i></a>`

Comment: Gracias, funciona muy bien.